# Solve $\cos{z}+\sin{z}=2$

Tags: complex-numbers

I am trying to solve the question:

> > $\cos{z}+\sin{z}=2$
> >
> > Where $z \in \mathbb{C}$

I think I know how to solve $\cos{z}+\sin{z}=-1$:

$1+2\cos^2{\frac{z}{2}}-1+2\sin \frac{z}{2}\cos{\frac{z}{2}}=0\\
2\cos{\frac{z}{2}}(\cos{\frac{z}{2}}+\sin{\frac{z}{2}})=0$

etc... (that is, if the double angle identity holds true when the 'angle' is a complex number - I might be wrong about this)

My other methods involve:

- trying to substitute $\cos{z}=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$ and $\sin{z}=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$. This seems to be the most obvious method, but I can't work out the next step after $$e^{iz}-e^{-iz}+(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})i=4i$$
- substituting $2=2(\sin^2{z}+\cos^2{z})$
- substituting $\sin{z}=\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-z)$ (again, not really sure if this can be done)

[image]

Comment: **Hint:** $a+b=2,~a^2+b^2=1$.

Comment: Where did you get that from?

Comment: The functional relation between the sine and cosine function holds for all values of the argument, not just real ones. Then $4=2^2=(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab=1+2ab$, from which we deduce that $ab=\dfrac32$. But now that we know their sum and their product, it follows that $\cos z$ and $\sin z$ are the roots of the equation $(t-s)(t-p)=t^2-st+p=0$, where $s=2$ and $p=\dfrac32$ are the sum and product, respectively.

Comment: I would try using the formula
$$\cos z+\sin z=\sqrt2\sin(z+\frac\pi4)$$ that holds for all complex numbers $z$ (as do the other trig identities as also pointed out by Lucian).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Recall that the addition formula for cosines reads $$\cos(z+z')=\cos z\cos z'-\sin z\sin z',$$ and that, for $z'=-\pi/4$, one gets $$\cos(z-\pi/4)=(\cos z+\sin z)/\sqrt2.$$ Hence the equation to be solved is $$\cos(z-\pi/4)=\sqrt2.$$ To go further, consider $$u=\mathrm e^{\mathrm i(z-\pi/4)},$$ then $u\ne0$ and the equation above reads $$u+u^{-1}=2\sqrt2,$$ that is, $$u^2-2\sqrt2u+1=0=(u-\sqrt2)^2-1,$$ that is, $$u=\sqrt2\pm1.$$ Thus, the complex number $$\mathrm i(z-\pi/4)-\log(\sqrt2\pm1)$$ must be a multiple of $2\mathrm i\pi$, that is, finally, and since $\sqrt2\pm1$ are respective inverses, $$z=\pm\mathrm i\log(\sqrt2+1)+\pi/4+2n\pi,\qquad n\in\mathbb Z.$$ Note that here, $\log$ is the usual function logarithm defined on the positive real half-line.

Comment: very nice initial hint!

Comment: I don't understand why $\cos(z-\pi/4)=(\cos z+\sin z)/\sqrt2$. Is this an identity?

Comment: It's the angle sum identity for $cos(a+b)$.  $\sin(\pi/4)=\cos(\pi/4)=1/\sqrt{2}$

Comment: See new first sentence.

Comment: How did you get $u+u^{-1}=2\sqrt{2}$? And why is $\mathrm i(z-\pi/4)-\log(\sqrt2\pm1)$ a multiple of $2i\pi$? Doesn't it equal $0$ since $u=\mathrm e^{\mathrm i(z-\pi/4)}$?

Comment: First question: because $\cos(z-\pi/4)=(u+u^{-1})/2$. Second question: To know that $e^{w}=t$, for some $t\ne0$, is to know that $w-y$ is a multiple of $2i\pi$, for any $y$ such that $e^y=t$. For example, $e^w=1$ implies that $w$ is a multiple of $2i\pi$ (since $1=e^0$), not that $w=0$.

Answer (score 1):

A hint: The formula
$$\cos x+\sin x=\sqrt{2}\>\sin\left(x+{\pi\over4}\right)$$
known from high-school trigonometry also holds for complex $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another answer:

First, let's recognize why we need to go to complex variables. Recalling that $\cos\frac{\pi}{4}=\sin\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, we have from the cosine addition formula

$$\sin z+\cos z = \sqrt{2}\cdot\left[\sin\frac{\pi}{4}\sin z+\cos\frac{\pi}{4}\cos z\right]=\sqrt{2}\cos\left(z-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$ as several other answers have already noted. This has a maximum value of $\sqrt{2}$ for real $z$, so we'll need complex $z$ if we want to get a value of $2$ instead.

Keeping in mind that the closest approach for real $z$ was $z=\pi/4$, we make the substitution $z=\frac{\pi}{4}+i\tau$ with the anticipation that $\tau$ should 'mostly' be imaginary. Thus gives the equation $$\sqrt{2}\cos\left(z-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\sqrt{2}\cos(i\tau)=\sqrt{2}\cosh \tau=2$$ which immediately yields $\tau=\pm \cosh^{-1} \sqrt{2}$ as the principal solutions (recall that hyperbolic cosine is an even function). Thus $\boxed{z=\dfrac{\pi}{4}\pm i\cosh^{-1} \sqrt{2}+2\pi n}$ where we have taken into account the $2\pi$-periodicity of the trig functions involved.

Comment: This is *one half* of the set of solutions.

Comment: @Did: ...I do so tire of silly mistakes on my part. Thanks for the tip. Luckily it's something that's easy to fix within the framework of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$\cos(\arctan(z)) + \sin(\arctan(z)) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+z^2}} + \frac{z}{\sqrt{1+z^2}}.$$

So, if you can solve the equation

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+z^2}} + \frac{z}{\sqrt{1+z^2}} = 2,$$

(which is quadratic) then you can solve the original.

Comment: I can solve the quadratic but I do not know what to do with this to solve the original.

Comment: I get $\arctan(\frac{1}{3}\pm \frac{\sqrt{10}}{3})$, but that is real, not complex.

Comment: @ahorn I think you made a mistake in your solution of the quadratic.

Comment: @Did I guess we just apply the arc tangent.

Comment: $1+z=2\sqrt{1+z^2}\\ 1+2z+z^2=4(1+z^2)\\3z^2-2z-3=0\\z=\frac{2\pm \sqrt{4+36}}{6}=\frac{1}{3}\pm\frac{ \sqrt{10}}{3}\\ \arctan z=\arctan(\frac{1}{3}\pm\frac{ \sqrt{10}}{3})$

Comment: One problem with your answer is that $\arctan$ has period $\pi$ while the set of solutions of the original equation is $z+2\pi\mathbb Z$ for any solution $z$.

Comment: @ahorn You have a mistake in your 3rd line.  The $-3$ should be a $+3$.

Comment: @Did Have you tried plugging the solution into the equation? You'll find that both solutions work just fine, if you do.  Now I never claimed or wanted to present a full solution - the answer started as a hint. In particular, I never claimed that the solution set had period $\pi$, merely that the period is related to the period of the tangent. In squaring both sides, it's likely that some spurious solutions are introduced.

Comment: Frankly, I am a bit lost by your last comment... Anyway, if $z$ solves the equation, then $z+\pi$ does not, never. And if "Taking the periodicity of the tangent into account, you get two infinite families of solutions" does not suggest the contrary, I do not know what would.

Comment: @Did Have you tried plugging my solutions (the only two actually written down) into the equation?

Comment: Again? Whether I did or did not does not seem to be the problem here, you know. And yes, I did (happy?).

Comment: @Did And they worked - awesome! Now, $\sin(z)+\cos(z)$ has period $2\pi$ - done. :)

Comment: It seems you are more interested in stonewalling your answer than discussing its validity. Too bad. When you will be decided to discuss mathematics, just call me, until then...

Comment: @Did That's not true at all. Checking the solution against the *original* equation is quite a genuine suggestion. The original, $\sin(z)+\cos(z)$ has period $2\pi$, while the squared, $(\sin(z)+\cos(z))^2$, has period $\pi$ - thus the spurious solutions. Honestly, this is so elementary and encountered so frequently in pre-calculus, I assumed you saw it.

Comment: Once again, the problem is YOUR solution and your aim should  be to (try to) correct it rather than *testing* (rather ridiculously) those who mention problems in it. Enough for me.

Comment: @Did If there is a problem with this approach, I'd love to hear it. The only "problem" that you've alleged is that the solution set has period $\pi$ but, then, I never claimed that it does.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were on the right track. Putting $\;z=x+iy\;,\;\;x,y\in\Bbb R\;$ :

$$e^{iz}-e^{-iz}+(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})i=4i\implies e^{-y+ix}-e^{y-ix}+\left(e^{-y+ix}+e^{y-ix}\right)i=4i\iff$$

$$e^y\left(\cos x-i\sin x+i(\cos x-i\sin x)\right)+e^{-y}\left(\cos x+i\sin x+i(\cos x+i\sin x)\right)=4i\iff$$

$$e^y\left(\cos x+\sin x\right)+e^{-y}\left(\cos x-\sin x\right)+\left[e^y\left(\cos x-\sin x\right)+e^{-y}\left(\cos x+\sin x\right)\right]i=4i$$

And thus you get two equations:

$$\begin{align*}e^y\left(\cos x+\sin x\right)+e^{-y}\left(\cos x-\sin x\right)=0\\e^y\left(\cos x-\sin x\right)+e^{-y}\left(\cos x+\sin x\right)=4\end{align*}$$

If you add\substract both equations you get

$$\cos x\left(e^y+e^{-y}\right)=2\iff\cos x\cosh x=1$$

$$\sin x\left(e^y-e^{-y}\right)=-2\iff \sin x\sinh x=-1$$

You now have two transcendental, real equations to solve

Comment: Thank you. I understand your working up until you mention the word 'transcendental'. I haven't had much practice with hyperbolic trig functions.

Comment: Forget that word: you get two equations which aren't polynomial (of course, also not linear), so the way to solve here may need of non-standard-basic-analysis stuff.

Comment: In your second line after the colon, you missed out a minus. $-e^{y-ix}=-e^y(\cos x - i\sin x)$

Answer (score 0):

Now here is a purely algebraic solution. As you have noted, the problem is equivalent to $$(1 + i){e^{iz}} - (1 - i){e^{ - iz}} = 4i$$consider the new variable $x$ as ${x=e^{iz}}$in terms of the newly defined variable, the problem reads as$$(1 + i)x - {{(1 - i)} \over x} = 4i$$multiplying by $x$, we get $$(1 + i){x^2} - 4ix - (1 - i) = 0$$which is a standard second order equation. The solutions are $$x = {{4i \pm \sqrt { - 16 + 4(1 - i)(1 + i)} } \over {2(1 + i)}} = \left( {1 \pm {{\sqrt 2 } \over 2}} \right)(1 + i)$$so that $$z = {1 \over i}\ln x =  - i\left( {\ln \left( {1 \pm {{\sqrt 2 } \over 2}} \right) + \ln (1 + i)} \right)$$which is hopefully what you are looking for (note that a more careful analysis in the logarithm part yields solutions in higher Riemann planes).

Comment: The discriminant of the quadratic is wrong.

Comment: @Did Thanks, it is hopefully correct now.

Comment: This is easy to check using my answer.