# How do you do the following questions, finding solutions in z over Complex?

Tags: complex-analysis

a. $\cos{z} = \cos2$

b. $\cosh z = \cosh2$

c. $\cos z = \cosh2$

d.$\sin z = \sinh2$

e. $\cosh z = \sin2$

f. $cos z = -1$

g. $cos z = 2$

h. $\cosh z = 2i$

i. $\sinh z = 4i$

j. $\cos z + \sin z = i$

Comment: Use http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-to-prove-eulers-formula-eit-cos-t-i-sin-t

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please take the tour (http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to get acquainted with this site. In particular, please include your efforts on the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! It is recommended that you provide the work you have done so that people can help you better. As suggested by others, please invest a minute of your time to take the [tour of the site](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) 
and look at [how to format mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) on Math SE. Furthermore, I suggest 
that you bookmark this [very useful MathJax link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) 
for quick reference. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** You can use Euler's formula
$$e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$$
and other identities
\begin{eqnarray}
\sin\theta&=&\dfrac{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}{2i}\\
\cos\theta&=&\dfrac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}\\
\sinh\theta&=&\dfrac{e^{\theta}-e^{-\theta}}{2}\\
\cosh\theta&=&\dfrac{e^{\theta}+e^{-\theta}}{2}
\end{eqnarray}
$$\cosh \theta=\cos i\theta~~~;~~~i\sinh\theta=\sin i\theta$$
[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) you find some properties of trigonometric and hyperbolic functions. Also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function) helps you more. There are many solved examples in this site like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166562/solve-sinz-2?rq=1), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919230/solve-cosz-sinz-2?rq=1) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1772217/solve-sinz-1-in-the-set-of-complex-numbers?rq=1). After your works we wait for your attempts on these problems and you are welcome.